# Move To Specific Position in RecylerView while clicking on tab in Tablayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

Based on the JSON , I have to create the dynamic tab and below that there is Custom Recylerview(header+another recylerview).
On Click of tab , I have to go to specific header. Can't able to figure out ,how to go to specific header.Below is my code.

MainActivity:

```
menuRecyclerView.adapter = MenuAdapter(this,scroolToPositionList,restaurantDataHM,menuRecyclerView )
        menuRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
myTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                val position = myTabLayout.selectedTabPosition
                Log.e("position-----",""+position)
                (menuRecyclerView.adapter as MenuAdapter).setCurrentPos(position)
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
        })
```

Below is MyAdapter Class :

```
class MenuAdapter(private val context:Context,private val keyList:ArrayList<String>,private val restaurantDataHM:LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Menu>>,private val recyclerView: RecyclerView) :RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuAdapter.HeaderMyViewHolder>() {

    inner class HeaderMyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var title: TextView = itemView.header_title
        var foodRecyler=itemView.foodRecylerView
    }

    @NonNull
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MenuAdapter.HeaderMyViewHolder{
        val header = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.header,parent,false)
        return HeaderMyViewHolder(header)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return keyList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MenuAdapter.HeaderMyViewHolder, position: Int) {
                holder.title.setText(keyList?.get(position))
                holder.foodRecyler.adapter=ChildFoodAdapter(context,restaurantDataHM.get(keyList?.get(position))?.get(position)?.items, holder.foodRecyler)
                holder.foodRecyler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
                (holder.foodRecyler.adapter as ChildFoodAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    public fun setCurrentPos( index:Int){
        val key=keyList?.get(index)
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(index)

    }
}
```

Below is the image for the reference:
[image: Click Here]

Comment: Are you using nested `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @SamChen Yes I am using nested RecylerView